# A question was closed as duplicate. Why does it say "on hold" in my "favorites" list?

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, bookmarks, on-hold

This question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30572201/509868)) was marked as duplicate; it appears so on the main page:

> Why can we let a pointer of type char point to something that is const* [duplicate]

However, I have it also on my "favorites" list, and it says "on hold":

> Why can we let a pointer of type char point to something that is const* [on hold]

The difference is small but it exists. Is it a bug or a feature?

I tried refreshing the page; tried removing the "favorite" star-mark and re-adding it; the result is the same.

Comment: Nice find. Direct link: http://stackoverflow.com/users/509868/anatolyg?tab=favorites&sort=activity

Comment: Wow, I had no idea anyone could see my favourite questions!

Comment: @anatolyg We see everything.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2AWyT7lPpc

Comment: Never assume _anything_. ...The good news is, no-one looks at your favorites list anyway.

Comment: @JonasCz: they do, sometimes =) there was even a SO db query somewhere that allowed you to find out what users favorited your questions

Comment: [it is both](https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/a/a3/Not_A_Bug_-_Feature.jpg/212px-Not_A_Bug_-_Feature.jpg)

Comment: Same issue [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KzGjd.jpg). Links to those two questions [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296028/what-to-do-when-my-question-is-not-being-seen-a-lot) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296027/review-audit-bans-durations). They are closed as duplicates but the "Hot" tab shows [on-hold] instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Deduplicator says, nice catch!

This was caused by our `User.GetFavorites` using a query that listed the columns individually, and it didn't select the `IsClosedAsDuplicate` column (presumably because duplicates used to be tracked a different way). That meant its value always came back as false.

Fixed is build 3762 on MSE/MSO, and 2883 on other sites.

Comment: Wait, were you a Stack Exchange employee?

Comment: @dorukayhan Yep, I worked there from March to December last year.